# How to debug javascript with Eclipse running local Tomcat server

Tags: javascript, eclipse, tomcat

There are a lot of questions on SO about how to debug a standalone piece of Javascript - that isn't what I want. None of the previous Eclipse/javascript questions seem to be on point, which surprised me.

I am using Eclipse for Java EE (Neon, the latest version) to develop a JSP/servlet website - a **full** website, not just javascript, and not just java/jsp - everything together. I can compile my Java and "debug as" on an instance of Tomcat spawned by Eclipse, and the web pages show up inside of a window in Eclipse. I can set and hit Java breakpoints all day long while using "debug as" - but setting breakpoints in javascript doesn't do diddly squat. I've been having to run a standalone instance of Tomcat, deploy war files to it, wait for the war files to decompress, then debug my Javascript inside of Firefox. This is particularly annoying because I'm relatively new to javascript and am doing some complex things on the page (and truth be told, making some silly mistakes a compiler in a typed language would catch for me before letting me waste my time trying to run the code) and the "change, watch Eclipse chew deploying war, wait for Tomcat to chew uncompressing the war, test" cycle is just unacceptably long.

Isn't there an easier way to debug **BOTH** java **and** javascript from the same IDE without having to export and deploy WAR files? Is there is a setting I can toggle or something I can install in Eclipse to make it an all-in-one IDE? Ideally I would like to be able to step through, for example, an AJAX call into my servlet AND watch what happens in the javascript after it returns - within the same debugging session - so let me preemptively state that copying the changed js file(s) directly to the decompressed folder in tomcat/webapps as a faster way to continue to do split debugging is not the kind of "workaround answer" I'm looking for.

Comment: You can use external browser (i.e. your Chrome/Firefox/Safari/IE) to access the webapp running inside Eclipse, and use the browser's developer tools to debug the JavaScript, watch AJAX calls etc. If you haven't changed the default settings, the Eclipse's Tomcat should run on the default 8080 port.

Comment: Thanks - that's better than what I was doing [feeling the Homer Simpson "duuuooohhh" moment here]. So far nobody has come up with a truly integrated Eclipse solution yet, which sort of surprises me; that being said, I suppose that leveraging off of commercial browser 'debugging' is not a bad way to go, awkward though it might be.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript debugging is going to be supported in Eclipse **Neon 1** release **(September 2016)**. Here is a demo video in which step-by-step process of debugging both front-end and back-end is explained - https://youtu.be/7oQz1Ja1H08 .

Basically, running Chrome / Chromium with extra parameters and tuning source mapping manually is not really user-friendly now, but we are going to improve it for Neon 1 and future releases.
Contributions of any kind are most welcome ;)